# Rank of free group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, free-groups

Let $G$ be a free group with a basis $S$.

Let $G'$ be the commutator subgroup of $G$.

Define $S'=\{gG'\in G/G': g\in S\}$

Then, $S'$ is a basis for the free abelian group $G/G'$.

Following the above argument, How do I prove that $|S|=|S'|$?

Comment: If not, then you would have $g,h \in S$ with $gh^{-1} \in G'$, which is impossible because elements in $G'$ have zero exponent sum for all elements of $S$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Doesn't $gh^{-1}$ have zero exponent sum as well?

Comment: @Theo No, I meant the exponent sum of each individual generator. The exponent sums of $g$ and $h$ in $gh^{-1}$ are $1$ and $-1$. But for commutators, and hence for  all elements of $G'$, the exponent sum of each generator is $0$.

Comment: Right, right, apologies...

Answer (score 0):

[Free group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_group).  Let $G$ be the free group on $S$.  It consists of words ("strings") over the alphabet $S$.  For instance $S = \{a,b\}$.  Then if $x \in$ the commutator subgroup $G'$, then $xy = yx \ \forall y \in G$.  But take $y = aaa$, $x = b$.  Then $xy \neq yx$.  Thus if $|S| \gt 1$, $G' = \{1\}$, and if $|S| = 1, \ G' = G$.  Is that correct?  Then $G/G' \approx G$ in the first case and $G/ G' \approx \{1\}$ in the second case.